# How to debug source on Android studio

Tags: android-studio, debugging, jar, apk, reverse-engineering

Im actually trying to debug the 3rd app on Android studio. From now what i did, i extracted the jar for classes for readable format .
And converted that jar to .Java source file use Jadx

And i Imported them on Android studio, now I'm trying to debug the app, Before that as we now, need to add set debugging True, so I'm trying to edit the source , but it only shows the FILE READ-ONLY

Let me know the how to debug now !

Comment: Debugging using generated source code often does not work because of wrong line numbers. Debugging 3rd party app you don't have source code of is better on smali level. Jadx is capable of smali debugging apps. BTW: Jadx can directly open APK files, so JAR conversion is not necessary.

Comment: I try to reverse engineering of the app and need to collect the data. Now what's my procedure to do ??

Comment: Best for debugging is a rooted device as you then can use Frida for hooking methods of the app to extract data easily or install a new system root CA certificate that allows you to intercept traffic using mitmproxy, Fiddler or a similar proxy.

Comment: Im not trying to collect the Http traffic of the application. Im trying to get the data from inside the app. Let me know the way to do ??

Comment: As I wrote that is possible using https://Frida.re on a rooted device (or if you manually integrate FridaGadget into an Android app by decompiling it, adding the gadget and making it load at start-up). There are also some Frida based web UIs available which simplify app hacking. Search for frida and android and you will get quite a few tutorials.